# Realm.Io Android Most Frequented Value

Tags: android, realm

How can I get the most frequent value in Realm?

For ex :

```
Jack
Ryan
Lee
Jack
```

Jack is the most frequented value.

Answer (score 0):

Remember! Realm is a NoSQL object store!  It is lightweight, fast, and the objects it stores are just plain ole' Java objects.  There is no need for for the DB engine to "optimize" computations like this.  You can do it yourself, quite easily:

```
public String getMostCommonName(Realm realm) {
    RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).distinct("name");
    long maxOccurances = 0;
    Person mostCommon = null;
    for (Person p : results) {
        long n = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("name", p.getName()).count();
        if (n > maxOccurances) {
            mostCommon = p;
            maxOccurances = n;
        }
    }
    return mostCommon.getName();
}
```